# Dynamic transparency geometry in MFC

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I'm creating a new-UI walkthrough for my MFC application and want to highlight certain controls as the walkthrough proceeds. Specifically, I want to darken the whole window except the control I'm emphasizing.

I tried creating a partly-transparent black overlay using `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`, but this doesn't let me set a sub-area *completely* transparent.  [`UpdateLayeredWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatelayeredwindow) can do this, but I'm not eager to create a BMP/PNG file for every control I need to highlight.

Can I create the transparency geometry dynamically?  For example, can I draw bitmap transparency from scratch then load it into `UpdateLayeredWindow`?

I also need to be compatible with Windows 7 (despite its support EOL).

**Follow-up:**
Trying to paint transparent GDI+ regions, but doesn't work:

```
    void ApplicationDlg::Highlight(const CRect& rect)
    {
        CRect wndRect;
        GetWindowRect(&wndRect);
        Gdiplus::Rect wndRectPlus(wndRect.left, wndRect.top, wndRect.Width(), wndRect.Height());
        Gdiplus::Region wndRegion(wndRectPlus);
    
        Gdiplus::Rect controlRectPlus(rect.left, rect.top, rect.Width(), rect.Height());
        Gdiplus::Region highlightRegion(controlRectPlus);
    
        wndRegion.Exclude(&highlightRegion);
    
        Gdiplus::SolidBrush transparentBrush(Gdiplus::Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        Gdiplus::SolidBrush darkenBrush(Gdiplus::Color(128, 0, 0, 0));
    
        CDC* pDCScreen = m_WalkthroughDlg.GetDC();
        HDC hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(pDCScreen->m_hDC);
        HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, wndRect.Width(), wndRect.Height());
        HBITMAP hBmpOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hDC, hBmp);
    
        Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(hDC);
        graphics.FillRegion(&darkenBrush, &wndRegion);
        graphics.FillRegion(&transparentBrush, &highlightRegion);
    
        BLENDFUNCTION blend = {0};
        blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
        blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
        blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
        SIZE sizeWnd = {wndRect.Width(), wndRect.Height()};
        POINT ptSrc = {0,0};
        m_WalkthroughDlg.UpdateLayeredWindow(pDCScreen, NULL, &sizeWnd, CDC::FromHandle(hDC), &ptSrc, NULL, &blend, ULW_ALPHA); // TODO cleanup FromHandle refs
        m_WalkthroughDlg.BringWindowToTop();
    
        SelectObject(hDC, hBmpOld);
        DeleteObject(hBmp);
        DeleteDC(hDC);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create a mask by using `CRgn` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/crgn-class?view=vs-2019

It allows you to combine regions (if you need to highlight more than one area). You could then use `FillRgn` function to update the `hdcSrc` DC used in `UpdateLayeredWindow`.

Alternatively, if your highlights are rectangular, you could just draw rectangles on that `hdcSrc`.

Comment: Trying to use the GDI+ `Region` class since the GDI `CRgn` lacks transparency.  But must be doing something wrong, the overlay window isn't drawn.

Comment: Grateful if you could glance at the code I've updated my question with.

Comment: What do you see with this latest code? I'm not familiar with GDI+, but could take a look if you somehow attach your project here.

Comment: The window is entirely 100% transparent, despite verifying that the control Rect is considerably smaller than the window Rect.  Unfortunately I'm unable to share the project.

Comment: I really don't have time to create a dummy skeleton project to play with this. However, you can go back to your original solution, but instead of one dark overlay create four to surround your highlighted control: one on top of it, one on the bottom and two on each side.